# Is there any way to get the error callbacks from In App Review API

Tags: android, kotlin

I was trying to integrate In App Review API.
reading from this doc [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/kotlin-java), but was unable to find solution for some of my edge cases.

**1. The user has already rated the app.
2. The quota limit has been reached.**

One [troubleshooting docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/test#troubleshooting) also Google provided, but it just tells, but it won't help technically. It will be good if we get the error cases. From the SDK or some 'other way'. So that I can handle these cases in my app, is there any solution for this scenario? Please let me know.

```
fun Activity.launchInAppReview(
    onComplete: () -> Unit,
    onFailed: () -> Unit,
) {
    val reviewManager = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        FakeReviewManager(this)
    } else {
        ReviewManagerFactory.create(this)
    }
    val request = reviewManager.requestReviewFlow()
    request.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            val reviewInfo = task.result
            val flow = reviewManager.launchReviewFlow(this, reviewInfo)
            flow.addOnCompleteListener {
                // The flow has finished. The API doesn't indicate whether the user
                // reviewed or not, or even whether the review dialog was shown.
                // Therefore, no matter the result, continue with your app's flow.
                onComplete()
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                onFailed()
            }
        } else {
            // Log or handle error if you want to
            onFailed()
        }
    }.addOnFailureListener {
            onFailed()
    }
}
```

Comment: If user already rated your app the In-App review never gets triggered and you will not be notified of that, same if user doesn't rate your app and just closes it, you'll only be notified of the process complete, not whether the user rated your app

Comment: OK, but my scenario is like first i will show a popup window to ask user whether he can rate our app please click here. then, once he click we can take him to the In App review SDK. again, for the same user already rate our app need not to show this confirmation pop up of right ?

Comment: The whole point of the In-App review API is that you don't need to do your own asking at all - the API takes care of only asking if the user hasn't already rated the app and if they haven't already been asked recently. You don't have to do any of that yourself.

Comment: Now it Make sense.  @ianhanniballake